# Axis of a Paraboloid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

> The elliptic paraboloid $$x = y^2
> /3  + z^2
> /7$$  is a bowl-shaped surface. Along 
>   which axis does the bowl open?

I don't even know to get started on this question. Thank you.

Comment: Plot the function as a function of $y,z$... Or have intuition tell you that it must be the $x$-Axis.

Comment: @AlexR Why does intuition tell you it must be the x-Axis?

Comment: Well because $x$ grows quadratic in $y$ and $z$, huh? Plot it I suggest.

Comment: Make three 2d functions by letting x=0, y=0, and z=0, and determine which function has a point of inflection.

Comment: Look at the level curves of the function for constant $x$